# Error 80004005: how to troubleshoot this?

Tags: asp.net, jet

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '\100.104.24.12\att2008\att2000.mdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.
>
> /functions.asp, line 36

Answer (score 1):

There is still a lot of detail missing to tell you definitively what the issue is, but try this anyway:

- the single backslash at the start of your UNC path is wrong, it needs to be a double backslash: **\**\100.104.24.12
- ensure that the next part of the path `att2008` is a valid share, not just a regular file system folder
- ensure that the credentials/identity that the ASP.NET process is running under has permissions to modify the mdb file
- use a tool like [ProcessMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to determine if another process is holding a lock on the mdb file